# JPA recursive one-to-one lazy-loaded reference not updated

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Using JPA 2.1 and Hibernate 4.3.6.Final, I have the following simple entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CONTACT")
public class Contact {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PARTNER_ID")
    private Contact partner;

    Contact() {
    }

    public void assignPartner(final Contact other) {
        this.partner = Objects.requireNonNull(other);
        other.partner = this;
    }

    public void unassignPartner() {
        if (partner != null) {
            partner.partner = null;
        }

        partner = null;
    }
}
```

Notice the lazy-loaded one-to-one recursive association to a partner Contact. Also notice how assignPartner() and unassignPartner() manage the bi-directional relationship.

And the following methods:

```
private static void assignPartner(final EntityManager entityManager) {
    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();

    final Contact contact1 = entityManager.find(Contact.class, CONTACT1_ID);
    final Contact contact2 = entityManager.find(Contact.class, CONTACT2_ID);

    contact1.assignPartner(contact2);

    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
}

private static void unassignPartner(final EntityManager entityManager) {
    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();

    final Contact contact1 = entityManager.find(Contact.class, CONTACT1_ID);
    contact1.unassignPartner();

    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

Assuming existing rows for CONTACT1_ID and CONTACT2_ID, after running assignPartner() then unassignPartner(), database state shows that contact1 has a null partner_id and contact2 still has a non-null partner_id.

However, if I change the Contact.partner fetch type to EAGER, after running assignPartner() then unassignPartner(), database state shows that both contact1 and contact2 have null partner_id.

Why is that? Why are changes to the partner entity not flushed to the database?

**EDIT 1**

Changes to the partner reference through direct field access, e.g. partner.firstName = "DUMPED", are not propagated either.
Changes to the partner reference through method access, e.g. partner.setFirstName("DUMPED"), are propagated.
Neither partner.partner = null or partner.setPartner(null) are propagated.

**EDIT 2**

As suggested by Rat2000, moving the unassignment logic outside the Contact.unassignPartner() method and inside the unassignPartner(EntityManager) method seems to work properly. So it's really something to do with how Hibernate deals with the contact1.partner proxy, and in particular the contact1.partner.partner proxy.

```
    final Contact contact1 = entityManager.find(Contact.class, CONTACT1_ID);
    contact1.getPartner().unassignPartner();
    contact1.unassignPartner();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.UPDATE)
@JoinColumn(name = "PARTNER_ID")
private Contact partner;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have tried it and the results are the same. Committing the transaction automatically flushes the EntityManager, so this should make no difference. Also, changes to contact1 are flushed to the database, but not changes to contact2. That's what I don't understand.

Comment: I think you have confused me... So when you save to the database, the changes apear in the database for contact 1, but if you retreve the object contact 2(witch should have a reference to contact1) from the database, Contact partner is null?

Comment: Contact.unassignPartner() unassigns the partner for the current instance (this) but also for the referenced instance (partner). So after calling contact1.unassignPartner() and committing the transaction, I'm expecting to have contact1.partner = null and contact2.partner = null, both in memory and in the database. I'm observing contact1.partner = null and contact2.partner = null in memory, but contact1.partner = null and contact2.partner = contact1 in database.

Comment: I'm afraid the result is the same. The problem isn't that contact2 isn't detached from the EntityManager, it's that it's just not updated...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60318/discussion-between-spiff-and-rat2000).